# TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am new to python and have hit a wall. I should count pearson correlation coefficient, but I have error. The only thing I can think of is that python requires different syntax.

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

data = pandas.read_csv('One_imortant_table.csv', index_col='Id')
corr1 = data['Numb'].corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
print(corr1)
```

TypeError:

```
--->  corr1 = data['Numb'].corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)        
TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

What am I doing wrong here? I have searched for this mistake, but can't find any more. I am using windows 10 with the latest version of python, coding in Jupyter.

Comment: Correlation measures the linear relationship between two variables. What you have, `data['Numb']`  is a single variable. You cannot calculate correlation coefficient for a single variable. What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Correlation should be calculated between two columns. The argument 'other' is the second column that should be used. For example, you could do something like that:

```
import pandas
import numpy as np

data = pandas.DataFrame({'Numb':[1,2,3],'a':[7,8,9]})
corr1 = data['Numb'].corr(data['a'],method='pearson', min_periods=1)
print(corr1)
```

This prints `1.0`

Answer (score 1):

You need at least 2 columns to calculate correlation. Try this to see if it works?

```
data.corr(method='pearson', min_periods=1)
```