# Unable to calculate Spearman coefficent for columns between two dataframes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset which is basically a list of list

```
data = [[(datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 10, 0), Decimal('7.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 11, 0), Decimal('2.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 12, 0), Decimal('43.6666666666666667')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 14, 0), Decimal('8.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 9, 0), Decimal('12.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 10, 0), Decimal('2.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 11, 0), Decimal('2.0000000000000000')), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 17, 0), Decimal('2.0000000000000000'))], [(datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 10, 0), 28.5), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 11, 0), 12.75), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 12, 0), 12.15), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 6, 14, 0), 12.75), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 9, 0), 12.75), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 10, 0), 12.75), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 11, 0), 12.75), (datetime.datetime(2018, 12, 7, 17, 0), 12.75)]]
```

It basically contains two lists each of them with a `date` and `metric` column. I need to extract the metric column values of each of the list and find a a coorelation between them.

Note: The dates are similar in each of the list

So first I load each of the list into pandas and set date index.

```
data1 = data[0]
data2 = data[1]

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)
df1[0] = pd.to_datetime(df1[0], errors='coerce')
df1.set_index(0, inplace=True)

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)
df2[0] = pd.to_datetime(df2[0], errors='coerce')
df2.set_index(0, inplace=True)
```

Now I merge the two data frames (both of them share the same dates).

```
df = pd.merge(df1,df2, how='inner', left_index=True, right_index=True)
```

Now my data frame looks something like this

```
                                     1_x    1_y
0                                              
2018-12-06 10:00:00   7.0000000000000000  28.50
2018-12-06 11:00:00   2.0000000000000000  12.75
2018-12-06 12:00:00  43.6666666666666667  12.15
2018-12-06 14:00:00   8.0000000000000000  12.75
2018-12-07 09:00:00  12.0000000000000000  12.75
2018-12-07 10:00:00   2.0000000000000000  12.75
2018-12-07 11:00:00   2.0000000000000000  12.75
2018-12-07 17:00:00   2.0000000000000000  12.75
```

Now I need to find Pearson and Spearman coefficient between the two metric columns (1_x and 1_y)

I am able to find Pearson coefficient by doing

```
pearson_coeff = df.iloc[:,0].astype('float64').corr(df.iloc[:,1].astype('float64'))
```

But for finding Spearman coefficent, I do this

```
spearman_coeff = df.iloc[:,0].astype('float64').corr(method="spearman", min_periods=1).df.iloc[-1]
```

But I get the error below

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/souvik/Music/UI_Server2/test61.py", line 85, in <module>
    print(df.iloc[:,0].astype('float64').corr(method="spearman", min_periods=1).df.iloc[-1])
TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'
```

I followed this post from stackoverflow
[TypeError: corr() missing 1 required positional argument: 'other'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44381891/typeerror-corr-missing-1-required-positional-argument-other) and did exactly as said but I still get this error.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same syntax as you did for `Pearson`:

```
spearman_coeff = df.iloc[:,0].astype('float64').corr(df.iloc[:,1].astype('float64'),method="spearman", min_periods=1)
```

Or more simply, because your values are already floats and `min_periods` is `1` by default:

```
# pearson_coeff = df['1_x'].corr(df['1_y'])
spearman_coeff = df['1_x'].corr(df['1_y'], method='spearman')
```

Output:

```
>>> spearman_coeff
-0.34874291623145787
```